# Get size of variable length array in llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

Consider I've the following code

```
void foo(int n){ 
   int arr[n];
  }
int main(){
  foo(5);
}
```

is there anyway to get the value of n (in this case 5) for the array in the function foo

This is what I've come up with so far

```
#include <clang/CodeGen/CodeGenAction.h>
#include <clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h>
#include <clang/Frontend/CompilerInvocation.h>
#include <clang/Basic/DiagnosticOptions.h>
#include <clang/Frontend/TextDiagnosticPrinter.h>
#include <llvm/ADT/IntrusiveRefCntPtr.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Module.h>
#include <llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h>
#include <llvm/IRReader/IRReader.h>
#include <llvm/Support/SourceMgr.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Instructions.h>

using namespace llvm;

int main(){
 llvm::LLVMContext *llvmcx;
 static llvm::LLVMContext MyGlobalContext;
 llvmcx = &MyGlobalContext;
 llvm::SMDiagnostic Err= llvm::SMDiagnostic();

 std::unique_ptr<llvm::Module> module=llvm::getLazyIRFileModule("test.ll",Err,*llvmcx,false);

    for (auto curFref = module->getFunctionList().begin(), endFref = module->getFunctionList().end();
 curFref != endFref; ++curFref) {
        for(auto bb=curFref->getBasicBlockList().begin();bb!=curFref->getBasicBlockList().end();bb++){
            for(auto ii=bb->getInstList().begin();ii!=bb->getInstList().end();ii++){
                        if(llvm::dyn_cast<llvm::AllocaInst>(ii)){
                          AllocaInst *t=dyn_cast<AllocaInst>(ii);
                              if(t->isArrayAllocation()) { 
                                  if (llvm::ConstantInt* CI=dyn_cast<llvm::ConstantInt(t->getArraysize()){
                                      // this if is not satisfied                                  
                                   }
                              }                        


                         }
                   }
             }
       }
}
```

Is there any other way to get the size of a variable sized array?

Comment: There might be an ArrayType involved, it has a method called getNumElements(). But LLVM IR is an assembly language, array lengths aren't checked. Accessing beyond the end of well-defined and frontends such as clang may reasonably want to use a zero-length array type for an allocation that has a nonzero size.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the last part of the answer.. from what I can gather using clang for this would be better you think?

Comment: If a is an array of size 7, then a[100] is either illegal or undefined in most programming languages. In LLVM IR it is legal (with different syntax of course), and the size given in the array *type* is not a hard upper bound on the size of the actual runtime array. This means that you can obtain a size from the type, but it may or may not mean what you want.

Comment: Understood.. thanks a lot!